# Dojo Splitter not working inside TabContainer

Tags: jsf, dojo, richfaces, splitter

Using the following code snippet, the splitter is displayed fine on the first tab that appears after transition to the current page, however the splitter doesn't show up properly in the subsequent tabs.

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" class="fitToHeight fitToWidth" tabStrip="true">
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" class="fitToHeight fitToWidth" title="Tab_1">              
    <a4j:include
        viewId="/view/syllabus/syllabusManagement.xhtml"
        id="container_syllabus">
    </a4j:include>
</div>
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" class="fitToHeight fitToWidth" title="Tab_2">
    <a4j:include
        viewId="/view/student/studentManagement.xhtml"
        id="container_student">
    </a4j:include>
</div>
```

Here's is the snippet of employeeManagement.xhtml/syllabusManagement.xhtml

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" design="sidebar"
    liveSplitters="true" class="fitToHeight fitToWidth">

    <div class="leftPanel" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
            minSize="5%" splitter="true" region="leading">
            Source Code Goes Here
    </div>
    <div class="targetPanel" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
            minSize="400" region="center">
            Target Code Goes Here
    </div>
 </div>
```

When the page loads, defaults to syllabusManagement.xhtml, the splitter functions as needed, but when i switch the tab to employeeManagement.xhtml, the splitters goes for a toss, gives real unpredictable behaviour.

My observation is that the splitter is rendered well when the tab is loaded on transition.

How do one fix this splitter rendering issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest using dojox.layout.ContentPane and setting the href attribute instead of loading all tabs at first.

your layout is needs to be 100% 100% for the tabcontainer and bordercontainer to calculate sizing properly.

See what happens here, if a width/height is not set [here](http://jsfiddle.net/seeds/aWWFL/1/)